# How to get a list of submenu within selected items of spinner in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt2Zs.png)

I try to design a spinner with a list of item to form a menu
my strings.xml looks like:

```
<resources>
  <string-array name="food_arrays">
    <item >meat</item>
    <item >Vegetable</item>
    <item >Rice</item>
    <item >Bread</item>
  </string-array>
    <string-array name="meat_arrays">
    <item >Lamb</item>
    <item >Chicken</item>
    <item >Beef</item>
    <item >Turkey</item>
    <item >Fish</item>
    <item >Shrimp</item>
    </string-array>
  ...
</resources>
```

In testing, I can select any item listed under array "food_arrays"
But I hope when I click Meat item in spinner, another dropdown submenu contains all items listed in meat_arrays will be  displayed and I can make selection such as Shrimp. so I can click Shrimp and get its results.

How to get a list of submenu within selected items of spinner in android??

Please help throw some valuabe lights

Thanks a lot!!

see screenshot
I need to add 2nd level dropdown menu

Comment: Any guru can throw some lights??
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is it a really tough question to fix??

Comment: did you find the answer?